# azure deveops don't run agents (stage) when changes are made to README.md OR to all *.md files

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In 'azure-pipelines-v2.yml' I am trying to make it so that any changes to all the README.md files in my project wouldn't trigger the agent's test.
[image]

I tried excluding all README.md files:

```
 paths:
    exclude:
      - pipeline/deploy-app-job.yml
      - '**/README.md'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for Trigger Path Include and Exclude.

This is my repo structure:

[image]

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - test/README1.md
    exclude:
    - test/README2.md
```

Commit on README1.md will trigger the pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Commit on README2.md will not.

[image]

Mentioned in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths

Wilds cards are supported for path filters. For instance, you can include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*

This will exclude all .md files in test folder

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    exclude:
    - test/*.md
```

This will exclude all .md files in your repo folders

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    exclude:
    - '**/*.md'
```

Pay attention to this: for example excluding **/*.md will exclude .md files in nested directories (e.g. test/README.md, but does not match .md files in the root directory (e.g. README.md)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Can you help me with this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74598350/azure-devops-yml-change-a-variable-to-true-if-only-readme-md-files-have-been-ch

Comment: Hi @newProgrammer.cpp , I could not access the link above, have you deleted the question?

Comment: Hello!
Yes I have deleted it , thanks!